# Declare struct with use of command line arguments

Tags: c

I'm trying to obtain a certain value from a command line arguments. Then using this value I will set the size of an integer array inside my struct.

My code:

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int size_of_heap = atoi(argv[1]);


    struct s_status
    {
        int block_size[size_of_heap];
        char status[size_of_heap];
    };
```

It gives me errors of "Invalid declaration of variable-length array".

I don't understand why it doesn't work, because size_of_heap should now be an integer after being converted from a string by atoi(), so block_size[size_of_heap] should be the same as having block_size[any number].

Thanks in advance

Comment: It needs to be a constant. C doesn't let you declare variable-length arrays. Try `malloc`.

Comment: @irrelephant Actually it does allow it. And did so for 13 years now ;-)

Comment: @irrelephant Err..depends on which standard you're using.

Answer (score 4):

[Variable length arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) were introduced in C99. If you can't use a compiler that supports a standard beyond ANSI C, declare your struct like:

```
struct s_status {
    int *block_size;
    char *status;
}
```

and use `malloc()` to allocate memory for the struct members at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a C standard (or compiler) that does not allow variable length array sizes. It needs to be a constant or you should create the `block_size` and `status` arrays using `malloc(size_of_heap * sizeof(arr_datatype))` instead.

```
struct s_stats
{
    int *block_size;
    char *status;
};

struct s_stats my_stats;
my_stats.block_size = malloc(sizeof(int) * size_of_heap);
my_stats.status = malloc(size_of_heap); // sizeof(char) is always 1
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because the compiler doesn't know the size your array will have (`size_of_heap` will only be known at runtime).

You should allocate the necessary memory at runtime, see [`malloc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc).

Answer (score 2):

Are you using GCC? If yes, you can compile it in C99 mode, by using the `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` option of GCC. By default, GCC only supports the old C89 standard, which doesn't support variable-length automatic arrays. If you are using another compiler, check its documentation on how to make it support C99 instead of C89.

The "new" (by now it's old already) C99 standard has been around for 13 years now. It's a good idea to use it when you can.